# Error deploying spring app on heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot

**Error on running `heroku open` after deploying**

```
Error: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/*.jar
```

I am not sure how to fix this. I added something like this in procfile looking at other SO questions.

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/RootScopeIT_Riot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
web: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war
```

On running `heroku open` gives this error.

Please help me to fix this. I have been struggling for days. Thank you

Comment: Do a `mvn package` and check the jar file name in the `target` directory. If you're using Spring Boot and planning to deploy to heroku, then packaging your app as a war file isn't the best idea. Just stick will the default jar!

Comment: Are you trying to run an executable WAR file? Or do you need Heroku to provide the Tomcat container?

Comment: I need to heroku to provide tomcat